# How to put a list of string in Flutter localizations?

Tags: flutter, flutter-localizations

I'm developen a flutter application and in order to internationalize it I'm using Flutter_localizations package. It works great and it is very easy to implement.

So, using this package I have a JSON file with some word with his translations as you can se here:

```
{
    
    "helloWorld" : "Hellow world!",
    "@helloWorld":{
        "description": "A programer greeting"
    },

    "team" : "Team",
    "@team":{
        "description": "Team text of buttom"
    },

    **"cart": {
        "one": "{{ count }} item in your Shopping cart",
        "other": "{{ count }} items in your Shopping cart"
    }**

    **"test" : ["test"],
    "@test":{
        "description": "car text of buttom"
    }**
}
```

However, I want to put a list of string as you can see in the key cart or in the key test, but flutter localizations doesn't like something like that and it give me the error:

```
Generating synthetic localizations package failed with 2 error:

Exception: The value of "cart" is not a string.
Exception: The value of "test" is not a string.
exit code 1
```

Does anyone now how to put a list of string in order to translate that list using flutter localizations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List also need to be defined as seperate list items for Flutter Localization like below inside .arb file:

```
  "yourTextList0": "I'm learning",
    "yourTextList1": "Good job",
    "yourTextList2": "Almost done",
```

Then you need to assign this values and create a list where you will use it.

Note: This example is for Flutter Intl localization implementation. If you use raw localization by only l10n.yaml option you may need to use different format and define the type as well:

```
"yourTextList[0]": "I'm learning",
"@yourTextList[0]": {
    "type": "text"
  },

 "yourTextList[1]": "Good job",
"@yourTextList[1]": {
    "type": "text"
  },

"yourTextList[2]": "Almost done",
"@yourTextList[2]": {
    "type": "text"
  },
```

Then use it like normal list:

```
DropdownButton(
                                value: yourDefaultValue,                                
                                onChanged: (value) {
                                  // have fun, do something here
                                },
                                items: S
                                    .of(context)
                                    .yourTextList
                                    .map((value) {
                                  return DropdownMenuItem(
                                      child: new Text(value,
                                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
                                      value: value);
                                }).toList(),
 ),
```

Answer (score 0):

you can see the docs for ARB here

`https://www.applanga.com/docs/formats/arb`

Hope this example will help you.