# Using Localization inside a list - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

My application contains localizations (translation "en","ar"), in my translation JSON files there are cities that users will choose while registration process these cities appears in a DropDownButtonFormField widget as follows:

```
final provincesField = DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
      value: dropDownValue,
      onChanged: (String? newValue) {
        setState(() {
          dropDownValue = newValue!;
        });
      },
      items: provinces.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value: value,
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 100.0,
              child: Text(value, textAlign: TextAlign.center),
            ));
      }).toList(),
      elevation: 4,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.flag_circle),
        labelText: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.chooseProvinence,
        alignLabelWithHint: true,
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

the cities are declared in this list:

```
List<String> provinces = [
    'عمان',
    'إربد',
    'الزرقاء',
    'المفرق',
    'الطفيلة',
    'عجلون',
    'معان',
    'الكرك',
    'مادبا',
    'العقبة',
    'البلقاء',
    'جرش'
  ];
  String dropDownValue = 'عمان';
```

what am trying to achieve is that cities will appear to user based on the app language. I have tried to use `AppLocalizations.of(context)!.city` inside of the list but its not working so i believe there is some way to declare the list values based on localization, ill appreciate any help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to put a list of string in Flutter localizations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72438397/how-to-put-a-list-of-string-in-flutter-localizations)

Comment: @VladimirGadzhov it may resolve my question but actually its not very clear answer for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose below localizations data is your cities list

English:

```
  "Dhaka" : "Dhaka",
  "Chittagong" : "Chittagong",
  "Cumilla" : "Cumilla",
  "Rajshahi" : "Rajshahi",
  "Bhola" : "Bhola",
```

Arabic:

```
  "Dhaka" : "دكا",
  "Chittagong" : "شيتاغونغ",
  "Cumilla" : "كوميلا",
  "Rajshahi" : "راجشاهي",
  "Bhola" : "بولا",
```

initialize your the localization keys of your cities and dropDownValue

```
  List<String> provinces = [
    "Dhaka",
    "Chittagong",
    "Cumilla",
    "Rajshahi",
    "Bhola",
  ];
  String dropDownValue = 'Dhaka';
```

here is the widget. I used getx localization. So I used 'tr' after the child text of DropdownMenuItem. I hope it's can help u.

```
  Widget TestWidget() {
    return DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
      value: dropDownValue,
      onChanged: (String? newValue) {
        // To print the value with localization
        print(newValue!.tr);
      },
      items: provinces.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(value: value, child: Text(value.tr));
      }).toList(),
      elevation: 4,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.flag_circle),
        labelText: 'Select',
        alignLabelWithHint: true,
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

If you need to store the city in database or anywhere with localization then you can use it like [dropDownValue.tr]